# loopj on progress is not working as expected

Tags: android, loopj

I'm experiencing a really weird behavior of onProgress when uploading file with loopj from android app.
I'm uploading multiple files one after another using SyncHttpClient, 
but onPorgress is always being fired with some numbers that look like a hardcoded or fixed numbers rather than the actual size of the binary asset and the bytes already uploaded.
Here is the example output I'm getting

```
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 3353492 from 3353528 (100%)
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 3353528 from 3353528 (100%)
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 1338 from 2417 (55%)
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 2417 from 2417 (100%)
```

And then the same exact sequence of calls happens for every single file uploaded. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. BTW, the files upload fine, I just cant get the load indicator to work properly.

Here is the code sample:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        waveOperation = new WaveOperation();
        waveOperation.execute();

    }
//inner asynchTask class
    private class WaveOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            waveAll(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }


        private void waveAll(Context context) {
            String[] projection = new String[]{
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
            };

            String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " > ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(ApplicationContextProvider.getCurrentAssetDateTime().getTime())};
            final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection,
                            selectionArgs, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " ASC");

            while (cursor.moveToNext() && !isCancelled()) {
                final String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
                File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
                if (imageFile.exists()) {   // is there a better way to do this?

                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
                    int orientation = cursor.getInt(5);

//                    Log.d("###################### orientation: ", String.valueOf(orientation));
                    long timeTaken = cursor.getLong(3);
                    final String dateTaken = simpleDateFormat.format(timeTaken);
...
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(orientation);

                    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true); // rotating bitmap
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                    try {
                        EWImage.uploadPhoto(stream.toByteArray(), dateTaken + ".jpg", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
//this is the method that is not being fired often enough during the upload
//and when it's called, it report some weird numbers that look always the same regardles
//of file being uploaded
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgress(int bytesWritten, int totalSize) {
                                        super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
                                        Log.d("--------------progress: ", String.valueOf(bytesWritten) + " of " + String.valueOf(totalSize));
                                    }


                                    @Override
                                    public void onStart() {
                                        super.onStart();
...
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
...
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
...
                                    }


                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        super.onFinish();
                                    }
                                }
                        );
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e("FileNotFound", e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }

        }

    }
```

here is the uploadPhoto method from EWImage class:

```
public static void uploadPhoto(byte[] photoByteArray, String photoName, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) throws FileNotFoundException {
    responseHandler.setUseSynchronousMode(true);

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("file", new ByteArrayInputStream(photoByteArray), photoName);

    UploadProgressActivity.currentRequestHandle =
            SYNC_HTTP_CLIENT.post(getAbsoluteUrl("/upload"), params, responseHandler);
}
```

and the SYNC_HTTP_CLIENT defined like the following in the base class:

```
protected final static SyncHttpClient SYNC_HTTP_CLIENT = new SyncHttpClient();

static {
    PersistentCookieStore cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
    SYNC_HTTP_CLIENT.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

}
```

Comment: If you just want to print file size then Why don't you print file size inside onSuccess?

Comment: Post few part of code

Comment: I want to print not the file size, but the progress of upload, while it's uploading.

Comment: Post your part of code. Without seeing code we can't suggest anything, you can print the things you want inside onSuccess()

Comment: just updated the original post with the code samples

Comment: Where did you previously take progressDialog?

Comment: What do you mean? The issue is not that the progress bar not updating, the issue is that the onProgress method is not being fired properly by the framework (or at least it seems that way). It's not called often enough to make the progress meaningful, and the numbers that are being passed to the method look weird -- always the same numbers regardless of the file size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58365/discussion-between-dmitryame-and-rit).

Comment: I'm fairly new to the loopj and still learning it. I'm finding, there are variety of different response handlers. I'm wondering if I should be using a specific subclass of AsyncHttpResponseHandler, perhaps DataAsyncHttpResponseHandler to make onProgress work correctly. Will give it a try next.

Comment: I guess, i was wrong, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

I did figure it out, 
it only works for File parameter, does not work for Stream or ByteArray -- seems like a bug in loopj.

Comment: Was this solved? Same problem here with `totalSize` always being 1

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of AsyncHttpResponseHandler you will notice that "sendProgressMessage" is also called when the request response is obtained. So that is what you see as the last two updates:

```
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 1338 from 2417 (55%)    
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 2417 from 2417 (100%)
```

About the first updates:

```
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 3353492 from 3353528 (100%)
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler﹕ Progress 3353528 from 3353528 (100%)
```

Keep in mind that probably any request header is also considered in the totalSize.